# Question about the general potential operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, potential-energy

The Hamiltonian operator is given by $$\hat{H} = \frac{\hat{\textbf{p}}^2}{2m} + \hat{V}.$$ For this reason it's of interest to know how to find $\hat{V}$ in any representation. Is the potential operator---independent of a chosen basis---given by $$\hat{V} = V(\hat{\textbf{r}}, t)$$ where $V(\textbf{r}, t)$ is the potential energy at position $\textbf{r}$ and time $t$? I know this works when dealing with the position representation.

Comment: I'm puzzled.  The potential is the potential, just like the kinetic energy is the kinetic energy. Are you asking if there are momentum-dependent potentials or if $\hat V$ has an expression in the momentum basis?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Perhaps it's that the answer to my question is "yes" and so it seems bizarre to you that I'd be asking if the potential is itself. I am not asking either of your proposed questions.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero The momentum operator $\hat{\textbf{p}}$ isn't the same thing as the momentum so it makes sense to ask how to represent it in any given basis. The same applies to the potential operator.

Comment: The position operator $\hat x$ is not the same as the position either...  Probably I just misunderstood your original point and it took me in the wrong direction.  Anyways I contributed an answer, if it's of any use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation you write does not assume a basis. In other words, the equation:

$$\hat H=\frac{\hat p^2}{2m}+\hat V(\hat r,t)$$
can be expressed in any basis we choose.

For example, in 1D we can choose to work in the position basis:
$$\hat H=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\hat V(x,t)$$
or we can work in the momentum basis:
$$\hat H=\frac{p^2}{2m}+\hat V\left(i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial p},t\right)$$
or whatever other basis you choose to work in.

Comment: What you're saying is that I can just plug in the position operator into the potential energy function, yes?

Comment: @PiKindOfGuy Yes that is what a function does.

Comment: Right, but that doesn't mean that the potential energy operator is the same as the potential energy function evaluated at the position operator.

Comment: @PiKindOfGuy why not? That is typically taught as one of the postulates of QM. In less formal language, you take your classical Hamiltonian and then replace the X's and P's with the corresponding operators.

Comment: Well, that's more information than "potential energy is a function of position and time."

Answer (score 2):

The potential operator is $\hat V$, and it’s independent from the representation you choose (as any good representative of a vector space).

Nevertheless, pick up a basis $|\alpha\rangle$ of your Hilbert space: in this representation you can express the potential as

$$\hat V= \sum_{\alpha_1,\alpha_2} V_{\alpha_1\alpha_2}|\alpha_1\rangle\langle\alpha_2| $$

Where $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ runs over all the vectors of the basis (possibly infinite, and if continuously infinite the sums may become integrals) and

$$V_{\alpha_1\alpha_2}=\langle\alpha_1|\hat V|\alpha_2\rangle$$
are the matrix elements of the potential in the basis you chose.

To reconnect this expression to what you already know, i.e. the expression in coordinate representation, we just have to do a little algebra, indeed if we apply the previous formula to the coordinate representation:

$$\hat V = \int d^3x_2\int d^3x_2 V_{\vec x_1\vec x_2} |\vec x_1\rangle\langle \vec x_2|$$

But as $\hat V$ is a function of the operator $\hat X$, it is diagonal in this basis so

$$V_{\vec x_1\vec x_2}=\delta(\vec x_1-\vec x_2) V_{\vec x_1}$$ and the integral simplifies thanks to the Dirac delta:

$$\hat V = \int d^3x_1 V_{\vec x_1} |\vec x_1\rangle\langle \vec x_1|$$

Using the completeness of the coordinate basis, you can write:

$$V_{\alpha_1\alpha_2}=\langle\alpha_1|\hat V|\alpha_2\rangle= \langle\alpha_1|\int d^3x\hat V|\vec x\rangle\langle\vec x|\alpha_2\rangle=$$
$$=\int d^3x V_{\vec x} \langle\alpha_1|\vec x\rangle\langle\vec x|\alpha_2\rangle $$

So, knowing the matrix elements of an operator in a basis, and knowing the transition functions $\langle\vec x|\alpha_2\rangle$, you can express the potential in any other representation.

As others have already pointed out, for the momentum the transition functions are well known so this transition is almost harmless.

Comment: Are you claiming that any operator can be written as a linear combination of the outer products of the basis kets?

Comment: Yes; what I wrote is nothing more than $\hat V=\mathbb I\hat V\mathbb I$ where $\mathbb I$ is the identity operator, which you can express using completeness of basis vectors;

Comment: Also, I’m implicitly referring to 1-particle potentials, that means particle that depend only on the position of 1 particle, or on the distance between two particles; more complicated potentials may involve the positions of two particle separately, and the expression will have four indices instead of two, but the principle would be the same;

Answer (score 1):

Yes, usually the potential is written as a polynomial through a Taylor series which easily extends to the operator analog needed for quantum mechanics.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question of finding the potential in various representations (e.g. momentum space)

Comment: @GodotMisogi  How do you define a function of an operator for non polynomial functions, if not using a series representation?

Comment: So far what I've parsed from this answer is something like: Consider $V(x) = \sin x$, and expand it in a power series, then replace $x$ with the operator $\hat x$; it does not say anything about other representations (such as the momentum representation; OP mentions representations other than the position representation for context)

Comment: Well, the functions that don’t have Taylor series are indeed complicated and would warrant specific analysis. On the other hand, for the momentum basis, simply replace each X with ih(d/dp) which is X in the P basis. For example, X^3 would be a third derivative.

Answer (score 1):

In general, in the position representation:
$$
\hat p\psi(x)=-i\hbar \frac{d}{dx}\psi(x)\, ,\qquad 
\hat x\psi(x)=x\psi(x)\, ,
$$
and $V(\hat x)\psi(x)=V(x)\psi(x)$.

Of course in the momentum representation
$$
\hat x\psi(p)=+i\hbar \frac{d}{dp}\psi(p)\, ,\qquad 
\hat p\psi(p)=p\psi(p)\, .
$$
Usually it's not terribly useful to use $V(\hat x)$ in the momentum representation because it leads to a function of a differential operator.  However, there are two obvious and more interesting cases:

The linear potential $V(x)=k x$ becomes a simple derivative
$V(x)\psi(p)\to ik\hbar \frac{d}{dp}\psi(p)$.  This kind of linear potential finds applications when metals are plunged into magnetic fields (see Wanner, M., R. E. Doezema, and U. Strom. "Far-infrared surface-Landau-level spectroscopy in Bi." Physical Review B 12.8 (1975): 2883), or because the potential between quarks contains a linear part (see Fig.10 from [Drell, Sidney D. "The Richtmyer memorial lecture—when is a particle?." American Journal of Physics 46.6 (1978): 597-606.](http://inspirehep.net/record/129087/files/slac-pub-2074.pdf))

The linear potential is also useful in studying [quantum effects in free-falling particles](http://inspirehep.net/record/1397175/files/Pages_from_C15-03-21_115.pdf).

Of course in the case of a harmonic oscillator where $\hat H\sim \hat p^2/2m + k\hat x^2/2$, this becomes in the momentum representation basically the same as in the position representation up to some factor since $\hat p^2\psi(p)\to p^2\psi(p)$ but now $\hat x^2\psi(p)\sim -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dp^2}\psi(p)$